# data.table does not modify a column as expected

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a function

```
delete.all.after.pattern <- function (x,pattern) strsplit(x,pattern)[[1]][1]
```

and a data.table

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c("a","b\n undesired text","c")
dt <- data.table(a=a, b=b)
```

Thus I expect that `dt [, b:=delete.all.after.pattern(b,"\\n")]` would result in

```
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 c
```

instead of :

```
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 a
3: 3 a
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
dt [, b := sapply(b, delete.all.after.pattern, pattern="\\n")]
```

Your function is not vectorized and hence it only returns the first element, which is repeated for all rows.

---

Or you can call `strsplit` directly in `j`:

```
dt [, b := lapply(strsplit(b, "\n"), `[[`, 1L)]
```

You can also put the code into a function and call it as well

```
fun <- function(x, p) lapply(strsplit(x, p), `[[`, 1L)
dt [, b := fun(b, "\n")]
```

---

Another way is to use `data.table::tstrsplit` as follows:

```
dt[, b := tstrsplit(b, "\\n", keep=1L)]
```

Comment: your full answer clarified me about other R strucure issues, thanks a lot.